# I have Installed Magento 2 via composer on subfolder but the my site seems broken. CSS and JavaScript are not loading properly

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have Installed Magento 2.3.3 via composer on subfolder but the css and java are missed up

I am using WHM/Cpanel

[image]

Comment: Just run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and hopefully it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue after I ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.

So I needed to add en_US and no_NO after the command to make the website work again since we have Norwegian language pack installed. So for our case the website was looking for no_NO. so my question will be, so you have another standard language pack then english? (En_US)

Comment: I tired the static-content:deploy but still no luck, also I don't have other than En_US

Comment: Do you have the same issue on your Magento admin site? Or is it only showing on your website?

Comment: Yes also on the Admin site, like every where

Comment: Try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US / en_en if you have English instead of American English and clear cache and reindex

Comment: Tried it but still the same problem